# How to Update values in an independant component in angular 2+

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-services, angular-components

I am new to angular, i have managed to create a basic app which have multiple layout and in the profile edit page, when i update the user details and click save i want to make reflect this change in the header of the app( component)

I have created a sample app which somewhat look like the basic model of my app.

Please see https://angular-component-communication.stackblitz.io or edit https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-component-communication

i am initially setting some values to local-storage (in app.component.ts) and display those values in header(./app/_layout/app-header/) such as name, email etc.

What i am trying to achieve in this sample app is to change the local storage value from completely independent component and make the changes reflect in header.

please find my sample code below

### app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent  {

  constructor(){
     //since we dont have a login in this sample code iam manually setting the localstorage values 
    const initialAuthUserData = {
          token:'init-SOMETOKENSTRINGGOESHERE',
          name:'wilson',
          email:'wil@yopmail.com',
          is_admin:1,
          avatar:'init-avatar.jpg',
          user_id:1234
      };
    localStorage.setItem('authUser', JSON.stringify(initialAuthUserData));   
  }
}
```

### app.routing.ts

```
const mainRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: ApplicationLayoutComponent, 
        children: [
          { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full'}
        ]
    },
    { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];
```

### user.service.ts

```
export class UserService {
    constructor() { }

    setUser() {
      //In real app case i would be implimenting a auth check action and will set localStorage value on success 
      const userDataNewData = {
          token:'SOMETOKENSTRINGGOESHERE',
          name:'wade wilson',
          email:'wilson@yopmail.com',
          is_admin:1,
          avatar:'avatar.jpg',
          user_id:123
      };
      // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
      localStorage.setItem('authUser', JSON.stringify(userDataNewData));   
    }
    getUser() {
      const AuthUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('authUser'));
      return AuthUser;
    }
}
```

### app-header.component.ts

```
export class AppHeaderComponent{

  userData:any = {};
  constructor(private userService:UserService) { 

    //from user data variable i print user details on app header
    this.userData = userService.getUser();

  }
}
```

### app-header.component.html

```
<a class="nav-link">Hello {{userData.name}} (<small>{{userData.email}}</small>)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getter` for `userData`.

on `app-header.component.ts` file:

```
get userData():any {
   return this.userService.getUser();
};
```

instead of:

```
userData: any;
```

check this example I made:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-component-communication-fuautm?file=app%2F_layout%2Fapp-header%2Fapp-header.component.ts

Comment: iam sorry i couldn't  understand getter from plunker, it doesn't looks like the one i need.if its not too much, can you edit my stack blits? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-component-communication

Comment: sure, take a look at `app-header.component`:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-component-communication-fuautm?file=app%2F_layout%2Fapp-header%2Fapp-header.component.ts

Comment: sorry for being late for the reply. its working but i have another situation too with same condition, in which that section call an http request and display the output header. so i cant assign a direct api request response to return in getter. for sample plz check  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-component-communication-7g2g5d